# Maximum number of simultaneous MediaRecorder instances on android?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I created android app that records device screen (using [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html)) API and video from camera at the same time. I use MediaRecorder in both cases. I need a way to find out whether device is actually capable of recording two video streams simultaneously. I assume there is some limit on number of streams that can be encoded simultaneously on given devices but I cannot find any API on android platform to query for that information.

Things I discovered so far:

Documentation for [MediaRecorder.release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#release()) advises to release MediaRecorder as soon as possible as:
*" Even if multiple instances of the same codec are supported, some performance degradation may be expected when unnecessary multiple instances are used at the same time."*
This suggests that there's a limit on number of instances of the coded which directly limits number of MediaRecorders.

I've wrote testing code that creates MediaRecorders (configured to use MPEG4/H264) and starts them in a loop - On Nexus 5 it always fails with `java.io.IOException: prepare failed` when calling prepare() on 6th instance. This suggests you can have only 5 instances of MediaRecorder on Nexus5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything you can query for this information, though it's possible something went into Lollipop that I didn't see.

There is a limit on the number of hardware codec instances that is largely dependent on hardware bandwidth.  It's not a simple question of how many streams the device can handle -- some devices might be able to encode two 720p streams but not two 1080p streams.

On some devices the codec may fall back to a software implementation if it runs out of hardware resources.  Things will work but will be considerably slower.  (I've seen this for H.264 decoding, but I don't know if it also happens for encoding.)

I don't believe there is a minimum system requirement in CTS.  It would be useful to know that all devices could, say, decode two 1080p streams and encode one 1080p simultaneously, so that a video editor could be made for all devices, but I don't know if such a thing has been added.  (Some very inexpensive devices would struggle to meet that.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on devices and ram capacity ... you could read the buffers for screen and cam as much as you like but only one read at a time not simultaneously I think to prevent concurrency but honestly I don't really know for sure