# Android crash when using 2 MediaRecorder Instances

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-videoview

I'm developing an android application which requires to have 2 video recordings at the same time. I have my first MediaRecorder object starts a recording at 0 seconds. Then, I want my second MediaRecorder object to starts recording at 18 seconds. Finally, the first recorder will stop at the 20th seconds. Between 18 and 20 seconds, I will have 2 recoding instances.

However, the app crashes upon the start method (recorder.start()) execution of the second MediaRecorder object. I have been trying the find a work around for 2 days.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour for multiple instances of MediaRecorder is unspecified afaik and may or may not work depending on the device.

The documentation doesn't mention whether multiple instances are supported:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

There are complaints about crashes when instantiating more than one instance:

[Maximum number of simultaneous MediaRecorder instances on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893324/maximum-number-of-simultaneous-mediarecorder-instances-on-android)

[Android: Two instances of Media recorder at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140703/android-two-instances-of-media-recorder-at-same-time)

If the device can is capable of recording two video streams simultaneously, then it may work. But afaik this is not part of [CTS](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/index.html).